# SVN Maintenance

Tags: svn, version-control

We have been using SVN at my workplace for a few years now and we really haven't done any kind of maintenance on it besides updates and backups since we installed it.  Is there anything else we should be doing to maintain SVN or is what we've done all we really need to do?

Comment: What kind of maintenance do you have in mind? Generally as long as things are running fine, there's nothing you need to do. If you're using fsfs, then things are probably fine.

Comment: I'd advise you to move to FSFS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Repository Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html) in the svnbook, especially the [Cleanup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.2) section.

> Your Subversion repository will generally require very little
>   attention once it is configured to your liking. However, there are
>   times when some manual assistance from an administrator might be in
>   order. The svnadmin utility provides some helpful functionality to
>   assist you in performing such tasks as
>
> - modifying commit log messages,
> - removing dead transactions,
> - recovering “wedged” repositories, and
> - migrating repository contents to a different repository.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion is basically maintenance-free if you are using FSFS on the back end. The BDB back end is a little touchier.

If you're using 1.6 (quite recent) on the server, you should consider doing a dump/reload and then running `svnadmin pack` to take advantage of server-side improvements in FSFS which make the repository more space-efficient.

Comment: I was thinking, in particular of the last two paragraphs of this section: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05.html#svn-ch-5-sect-1.3.1 when I wrote that.

Comment: At work we run a SVN 1.2 server with several BDB repositories. Probably every 6 months, we have a BDB repository "lock up" which requires manual intervention to get that repository going again. No data loss, just a locked database transaction. Newer versions of SVN server should be able to self-recover in that scenario. We just haven't got around to upgrading yet.